# Replace a certain String with iText TextField in ListArray

Tags: java, arraylist, itext, textfield

Using of iText I want to create a pdf document containing table with values from file DB. Next step, before putting values into the table I want to find **values** that are matching the **pre-defined keyword** and **replace** them with **TextFields**. Thus, Text Fields should be in appropriate cells, i.e. if the keyword was at the 2nd row and 3rd column, then a this cell should be a text field inserted. To perform this I wrote the following method:

```
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("filedb.txt"));
    scan.useDelimiter(",|" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    int i = 0;
    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        String t1 = scan.next();
        String t2 = scan.next();
        String t3 = scan.next();
        String t4 = scan.next();

        // Puts all columns into the ArrayList
        List<Object> allColumns = new ArrayList<Object>();
        allColumns.add(t1);
        allColumns.add(t2);
        allColumns.add(t3);

        // *UPDATED* checks for 'keywrd' in columns and replaces them with TXT_FLD
        for (int n=0; n < allColumns.size(); n++) {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.setCellEvent(new TextFields(n));

            if (allColumns.get(n).equals("keywrd")) {
                allColumns.set(n, cell);
            }
        }

        // Inserts all columns into the table cells 
        for (PdfPCell values : allColumns) {
            table.addCell(values);
        }

        // creates TextFields at the last column of a given table
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setCellEvent(new TextFields(i));
        table.addCell(cell);
        i++;
    }
    scan.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Error:**

> The method add(PdfPCell) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

How to adapt above structure code in order to perform replace method according the keyword?

Comment: I don't understand your code, nor your requirement. Maybe you should make a drawing that shows what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie please, have a look to the update part of the question.

Comment: That's not an iText question. It's a programming question. Instead of a `List` of `String` values, `updColumns` should be a `List` of `PdfPCell` values. Whenever **keywrd** is encountered, you should create a cell like the one in the fourth column.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I've uptated the method following your suggestion, i.e. used `Object` type, but it still doesn't want to apply for the `PdfPCell` type list. Could you please provide with some examples? Thanks

Comment: You're asking me to write your code. AFAIK that's not done on SO. Furthermore: you have a programming problem that isn't related to iText whatsoever. I can't fix code I don't understand. Look at `updColumns`. You define it, but you don't use it anywhere. And why is `allColumns` and array of `Object`? Ask the person sitting next to you to look at your code. He'll probably say he doesn't understand your code either, because it doesn't seem to make sense.